# Phase difference between current and voltage related to the frequency of the applied field

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, solid-state-physics

I know that in a plasma the complex electrical conductivity is:
$$ \sigma _n = \frac{Nq^2}{m(\tau^{-1} - i\omega)}$$

My book suggests that voltage and the current in the material have a phase difference dependent on the frequency of the oscillating electric field. However, I do not understand what is the relationship between the frequency and this phase difference.

***My question is:***
How can I derive the formula for the phase difference angle between the current and the voltage in the plasma?

Comment: $\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}$, so if you know the phase of $\sigma$, you can get the phase difference between $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{J}$. You can use the usual rules of complex math to find the phase of $\sigma$.

Comment: @daljit97 Edit your question and add what you have done to find an answer so the closure can be removed--send me a message when you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phase difference (or phase angle) in a 'load' is a function of the load's complex impedance and also the frequency of the applied voltage.  So in your case plug in the numbers and write conductivity

$$\sigma _n = \frac{Nq^2}{m(\tau^{-1} - i\omega)}$$

as a complex number and then convert it to an impedance $R +iZ$. (There is a reciprocal relationship between the two.) Then the phasor's angle will be the phase shift between the voltage and the current at frequency $\omega$ .

The imaginary component of conductance arises from either capacitance or inductance in the impedance (or conductance), and the impedance of either of these is a function of frequency. Since v=iZ (re. v=iR), a phase angle in Z causes a phase shift between i and v.

Google impedance, and see impedance of inductors and capacitors.  For example:

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-5/series-r-l-and-c/

The impedance of an inductor is

$$Z_L = 2\pi fL$$

The impedance of a capacitor is

$$Z_C = 1/(2\pi fC)$$.

These are both imaginary components of $R+iZ$.

To see why there is a phase shift between voltage, $V$, and current, $I$, use Ohm's Law:

$$V=I(R+iZ)$$ .

*The angle of the phasor $R+IZ$ is the phase difference between $I$ and $V$, and Z is a function of frequency.*

Comment: Ok so writing the conductivity as a complex number $A +iB$ and then converting into polar form gives the phase difference (from the angle) right? However, I do not understand why is this the case? Could you explain yourself a bit more or perhaps provide a good reference?

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: Yes to your question on converting the conductance to polar form.  And also See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_angle or en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance – user45664 Apr 24 at 17:41